# I can’t see the trigger I’ve created in arm-template-parameters-definition.json

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

The problem is, I’ve created in the arm-template-parameters-definition.json a trigger with the name “Test” this due the fact that I want to parameterize the triggers for the different environments. (see screenshot )
[Json template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM0wE.png)

I used the parameterization template in ADF for this. The code is ok I guess because, I can use the variable I’ve created in Devops. 
The thing is, I don’t see the trigger I’ve created in the section “Triggers” it’s still empty (on all the environment I’ve deployed) (see screenshot)
[trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKJ6n.png)

I’m missing something? Or did I forget something?

Comment: If you go resources.azure.com and navigate to the resource do you see the trigger defined in there?  This would be the actual arm deployment vs what the portal is showing.